# Bind DataSet on Window

Tags: c#-4.0, data-binding, wpf-controls

i want to create a window which will get some Data from DB.

I`m getting the data from database into a dataset.

Now i want to bind the dataset to the window, so that i can access in textblock, textboxes and some other controls in the whole window.

Is this possible or not.

Thanks

Comment: yes its possible, if you want to bind the data to textboxes check [Control.DataBindings Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.databindings.aspx)

Comment: I' ve found a solution how to bind the data to the controls